# Hibernate: How can I force hibernate to set types for collections?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm quite lost with a hibernate problem and hope that you can help me =)!

Here's my problem:

I have a Database with two tables, Addressbook and Contact, The relation between those is, in my scenarion, 1:n.

Now Hibernate generates me the following Code, after reverse engineering, in the Class "AbstractAddressbook":

```
private Set contacts = new HashSet(0);
```

But what i would need instead would be this:

```
private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>(0);
```

How can I accomplish this, where do I have to set it up for the reverse engineering?

Comment: Hibernate (and the JPA) are both strongly typed, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Post some of your entity code and what you're expected output is. What you're doing sounds like it is probably trivial but this isn't enough information.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish that my MySql database is mapped into Java classes, the only problem doing that is that Hibernate doesn't match Set<Type> correctly, as you can see above.

What kind of codepart would you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with MyEclipse, just add the HibernateTemplate that's coming with MyEclipse

I'd suggest you to follow this tutorial:

http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/hibernate/

Answer (score 6):

On Exporters in "Hibernate Code Generation Configurations" select "Use Java 5 syntax"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification (I've removed the garbage here). I can't say I have any experience with the Hibernate reverse engineering. I'd recommend using the Eclipse JPA tools (eclipse.org) and "generate the entities" from a new JPA project with a simple JDBC connection. (There are a lot of tutorials out there). It does a good job of mapping the database and it does a good job of inferring the correct types (you might have to change a Set to a List or little things like that). I ran this 4 days ago against a moderately complex database and it did a fine job.

Unless you have a bizarre requirement (like it needs to be in pure Hibernate XML configuration or something) the JPA tools generally do well and they're free. (A side note: JBoss tools, an Eclipse Plugin, should have Hibernate tools as well and might generate the xml mappings).

Comment: I think you got me wrong, I want to use Hibernate to generate DAO's and Abstract classes over the reverse engineering tool, in there is one section called "configure type mapping details" I guess I have to tell hibernate there somewhere the types of the tables, because so far it just creates a set without any type. Hope you know what i mean

Comment: I already have that, I use MyEclipse, which uses JBoss tools aswell (for the reverse engineering) and it generates all the AbstractClasses, normal classes, xml files and DAO files

the only problem, it doesn't map the Set (collection) type... and i really have no idea where to set it up in the "configure type mapping details"

Comment: A silly question, but why not just change it post generation? You can map a Set<T> type under the JPA. Again, are you using JPA Annotations or Hibernate XML?

Comment: I don't use any Annotations...my code is fully generated by Hibernate (the daos classes etc) so yes I use a hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: All I can say is post the configuration and a quick schema and I'll take a look at it. It seems like the correct solution is to override your class and provide the methods you need if you can't auto-generate it. Be warned, auto-generation carries a lot of problems down the road. It seems like a good idea until it bites you. Google for the .NET *.edmx files if you need a real world example. I'd just use the tool to make the class then keep it solid from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help! =) but I figured it out. I didn't use a hibernate template for the reverse engineering, so hibernate couldn't resolve the type for Set<>'s. Thanks for your help anyways =)! I'll keep your suggestions in mind!